# Changing fonts family in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, pubspec

I want to change the font family in `pubspec.yaml` but what happens when I run `pub get` isn't what I'm expecting. Here's what I did...

```
fonts:
  - family: Parisienne
      fonts:
       - asset: assets/fonts/Parisienne-Regular.ttf
     style: italic
     weight: 70
```

and what I got after running `pub get`

```
[creepy_ipad] flutter pub get
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 70, column 12: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?
   ╷
70 │       fonts:
   │            ^
   ╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at C:\Users\Khomotjo\creepy_ipad\pubspec.yaml
exit code 1
```

I honestly don't know what to do please help. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

It's indentation problem. Your *pubspec.yaml* should look like this:

```
fonts:
  - family: Parisienne
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/Parisienne-Regular.ttf
      style: italic
      weight: 70
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec#:%7E:text=The%20pubspec%20is%20written%20in,%2C%20fonts%2C%20or%20image%20files.) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

your style and weight should be align with the asset

For example:

```
      fonts:
       - asset: assets/fonts/Parisienne-Regular.ttf
<space>  style: italic
<space>  weight: 70
```

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts

Answer (score 0):

please config the space before start name with font...
number of space is important
change the amounts of spaces until underline is left.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).